# Proper way to check for array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Is this acceptable given that it's checking if there's an array PLUS checking the size of the array (where it may not exist)

```
if ( is_array($ar) && sizeof($ar) > 0) {}
```

or should it really be

```
if ( is_array($ar) ) {
  if (sizeof($ar) > 0) {}
}
```

Comment: Those two, apart from syntax errors, are logically equivalent.

Comment: You don't have to worry about the second condition if the first evaluates to `false`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is not aware of short-circuit boolean evaluation

Comment: @Phil that's not a good enough reason to vote as off-topic.

Comment: @Evert sure it is. This is a non-question as the two code snippets are functionally identical. This is due to short-circuit evaluation. OP's concerns about potentially executing `sizeof` on a non-array are unfounded.

Comment: @Phil: The two snippets being functionally identical is _literally_ the answer to his/her question.

Comment: The reason for the two conditions is because I have a further two conditions for the array if its size is 0 or not 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since PHP is not a language that enforces types (it is "loosely typed"), you can simply do this:

```
if( $ar && is_array( $ar ) )
```

This works because if the array is empty, $ar would evaluate as FALSE. If $ar is not empty, then is_array would make sure it's an array. By the way, this assumes that $ar is set. If $ar is not set, then checking it will give you a PHP notice. To be complete, if $ar may not exist:

```
if( isset( $ar ) && $ar && is_array( $ar ) )
```